# Different behavior of $() and ``

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution, command-substitution

```sh
% PATH="MYPATH"
% VAR="PATH"

% echo $(eval echo \$$VAR)
MYPATH

% echo `eval echo \$$VAR`
5707VAR
 ^^
This is the process number.
```

I thought those two were exactly the same, but obviously there are some differences, like escaping behavior. What are the differences?

Comment: The second should read `echo \`eval echo \$$VAR\`` (the `()` introduces an extra shell in your example). But yes, it works as you say.

Comment: BTW, you should write it: `eval 'echo "${'"$VAR"'}"'` or `eval "echo \"\${$VAR}\""`

Comment: This is so silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will reproduced the text of BASH reference manual because I will not express it any better:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they
>   may be removed during word splitting. The command substitution $(cat
>   file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Source: [Bash reference manual, Command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: To get the expected output, you have to escape the backslash with another backslash in backquotes: ``echo `eval echo \\$$VAR` ``

Comment: Or you simply use the other form ;-) there are many approaches to one problem: http://xkcd.com/399/

Comment: So is there any possible situation where you would prefer `\`\`` over `$()`? Up until now I actually prefered `\`` over `$()` since it is faster to type on [Neo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Neo) and doesn’t clutter the code as much. But with that escaping stuff…

Comment: @Profpatsch I cannot think of any useful or applicable example right now.